Why Won't the GNU FreeSerif Font Display Bold in Windows?
I've conducted an extensive search of free substitutes for Times New Roman, and after detailed comparisons, I've decided the FreeSerif font from the GNU FreeFonts is the best substitute.  Of course, none display exactly like it; but the letter forms of this one have the most similar feel and spacing (if I tweak the overall spacing between letters).  Sadly, they haven't been updated since 2012.
When I tried to use it as the main font in LuaTex, bolded text displayed only as regular text.  I've made a simple example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont {FreeSerif}

\begin{document}
    This isn't bold. \textbf{This is.}
\end{document}

If I set the font to Times New Roman, it shows bolded text just fine.  It also doesn't display right when I use the OTF font.  When I write a document in WordPad, I can set the font to "FreeSerif", and bold text in it just fine.  I have indeed installed the bold and other variants of FreeSerif.  I just can't get it to happen Latex.  Is there anybody knows how; or who can work it out?
Specs:
TexLive 2021, Windows 7 SP3 (still the best blend of features and privacy), the fonts from the "freefont-ttf-20120503.zip" archive (since they strongly recommend against the OTF fonts in Windows), and previewing in TexStudio with the Build engine "txs:///lualatex".
EDIT: After deleting the fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts from a CMD prompt, searching for them (?) with the command line with luafindfont freeserif, and re-installing them (a second time today, the first being before I posted this ?), it suddenly just started working.

no problem here ... What do you get if you run in the cmd-window: luafindfont freeserif

freeserif is part of texlive so you shouldn't need to get it from the upstream site it installs in /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/gnu-freefont (or your equivalent path for your tex distribution)

It definitely finds it, as it produces regular type.  If I delete freeserif*.* fonts, I get "Package fontspec Error: The font "FreeSerif" cannot be found."  If I do the luafindfont, I get "1. freeserif.ttf freeserif  c:/windows/fonts/", even tho I just deleted it for testing!

That's really weird.  I deleted the fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts, tried to run the example, it errored out.  I installed them again, and even tho I just installed them B4 posting this ?, it started working only after I REinstalled them!  It's been doing that for months previously.

you are only showing fragments of information but it would appear that luafindfont only found the regular not the bold font

Yet, it works correctly now, and LuaFont still finds only the one.  Just the one fragment, BTW.

luafindfont  searches the font database of LuaTeX, not the the system font directory. If you do not find a font, then run luaotfload-tool update and then try again the luafindfont. If the bold version again is not present, then it is not installed in a font specific directory.

I don't think that's true, but good info.  No separate bold font showing up in luafindfont, and yet it is in C:\Windows\Fonts, and is working after making me post this ?.  Perhaps the LuaFont command with the fonts gone, and then reinstalling them, fixed it tho, so thx hugely, guys.

Can you update your TeX distribution to TeXLive 2024? I have this system, and it has no trouble using the bold font weight of FreeSerif.

As above, no need.  It's working now.  I have no idea why.  I tend not to update softs very often, as it could break something  It does all I need for now, and it takes a LOOONG time to down and install.  Guess I might as well update it some day when I don't have more pressing life issues.  Be nice if you could also set it to just down and store the packages only when u need them.
